# CvVideoCamera processImage doesn't change the image

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, video

[Simple example](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html#opencviosvideoprocessing) of CvVideoCamera usage doesn't work as expected. The image modified in delegate's `processImage` is displayed with no changes at all.

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <opencv2/videoio/cap_ios.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnStart;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myimg;

@end
```

ViewController.mm:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <opencv2/videoio/cap_ios.h>

@interface ViewController ()<CvVideoCameraDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) CvVideoCamera *videoCamera;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:self.myimg];
    [self.videoCamera setDelegate:self];
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
    self.videoCamera.defaultFPS = 30;
    self.videoCamera.useAVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = YES;
}

- (IBAction)actionStart:(id)sender {
    [self.videoCamera start];
}

- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat &)image;
{
    cv::Mat image_copy;
    cvtColor(image, image_copy, CV_BGRA2BGR);
    bitwise_not(image_copy, image_copy);
    cvtColor(image_copy, image, CV_BGR2BGRA);
}
```

Once I press the button the normal camera stream is rendered with no traces of any interventions. I also tried to draw shapes and even calling `image.release()` inside of `processImage` with no effect.

I assume I'm missing something obvious here.
[There's the example repository](https://github.com/g-rad/opencv-ios-example)

[This is what I'm getting on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKEah.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line was the root of the issue:

```
self.videoCamera.useAVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = YES;
```

once removed, everything works as expected.